# How to use Serilog ForContext

Tags: .net, logging, serilog

I am new to Serilog and I am having a hard time figuring out how to use the context functionality. When I run the code below the output file does not include the the report id. Any ideas what I am missing?

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo
                .File(@"C:\Log.txt")
                .CreateLogger()
                .ForContext("Report ID", 10);

logger.Information("Test");
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Not all properties attached to a log event will be rendered by all sinks attached to the logger; the file sink used here only includes the timestamp, level, message and so-on.

To get the report ID into the file, include it in the sink's `outputTemplate`:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .WriteTo.File(@"C:\Log.txt",
    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:u} [{Level}] ({ReportId}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
  .CreateLogger()
  .ForContext("ReportId", 10);

logger.Information("Test");
```

This will include the report ID in each message.

`ForContext` is usually used to create a short temporary scope; if you want the same property on all messages you can use `Enrich.WithProperty()`:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .Enrich.WithProperty("ReportId", 10);
  .WriteTo.File(@"C:\Log.txt",
    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:u} [{Level}] ({ReportId}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
  .CreateLogger()
```

Flat files are a great way to get up and running quickly with structured logs, but using a data store more suited to structured storage, e.g. `CouchDB`, `RavenDB` or `Seq`, will make it much nicer to view and correlate events based on property values.

Comment: Changing to the JSON Sink (also targeting a plain file) allows structured logging (ie. all fields) and is easily ingested into Splunk, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Log using below code :

```
Log.ForContext("CategoryName", "CategoryValue").Information("My Info");
```

Then you can query it using below query :

```
select EventType,@Properties.CategoryName AS CategoryName,  @Message, @Properties
from stream  
where CategoryName = 'CategoryValue'
limit 1000
```

Comment: Where is this `stream` coming from?

Comment: @MEMark in his example, i believe he is querying his logs with Seq