# Serilog .ForContext not available via in service(/worker) class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, serilog, .net-6.0

How do I fix the dependency injection so that I can access `.ForContext(...)` within my worker/service class?

[.Net Core 6 for a hybrid console/WindowsService App]

In my main program class and worker/service classes, I have Serilog working correctly for basic logging...

Program.cs

```
Log.Information($"Application Directory: {baseDir}");
```

Worker.cs

```
_logger.LogInformation("Service Starting");
```

ServiceA.cs

```
_logger.LogInformation("In Service A");
```

However, the issue I'm having is that I need .ForContext to be able to work everywhere as well...  and it does in my main program class:

Program.cs

```
Log
   .ForContext("EventID", 42)
   .Information("Log This with EventID === 42");
```

... however, when I try to do the same in either of the worker/service classes ...

Worker.cs

```
_logger
   .ForContext("EventID", 42)
   .Information("Log This with EventID === 42");
```

... it does not work, and I get the following error:

Error   CS1061

```
'ILogger<Worker>' does not contain a definition for 'ForContext' and no accessible extension method 'ForContext' accepting a first argument of type 'ILogger<Worker>' could be found
```

... so I looked into that, and came upon the following SO questions (*neither of which was I able to apply, see comments in code below*) which were close:

- [Hot to get Serilog to work with Depedency Injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64866609/1327508)
- [Serilog DI in ASP.NET Core, which ILogger interface to inject?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61413261/1327508)
- [Inject Serilog's ILogger interface in ASP .NET Core Web API Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57285024/1327508)

... (*as well as some other places*) but I was unable to integrate the answers into the codebase:

Program.cs

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                // Configure the app here.
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                services.Configure<AppSettings>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
                services.AddScoped<IServiceA, ServiceA>();
                services.AddScoped<IServiceB, ServiceB>();
                
                //?? I'm not sure if this .AddLogging(...) is needed ??
                services.AddLogging(x =>     
                {
                    x.ClearProviders();
                    x.AddSerilog(dispose: true);
                });
                //?? ... having/not having it doesn't seem to affect execution 
            })
            .UseSerilog();
```

Worker.cs

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    //private readonly Serilog.ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    //?? ... wrt this attempt, Serilog.ILogger won't allow <Worker> ...

    //??    private readonly ILogger _log = Log.ForContext<SomeService>();
    //private readonly ILogger _logger = Log.ForContext<Worker>();
    //?? ... wrt this attempt, Log isn't available ...
    
    private FileSystemWatcher _folderWatcher;
    private readonly string _inputFolder;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IOptions<AppSettings> settings, IServiceProvider services)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _services = services;
        _inputFolder = settings.Value.InputFolder;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger
            .ForContext("EventID", 1001)
            .LogInformation("Service Starting - need to assign EventID === 1001");
        //?? here is where .ForContext is needed (but doesn't work)
...    ...    ...
```

Comment: @Dai I first tried to use `BeginScope`, however, it does not function the same when using a custom `eventIdProvider: new SERCrawler.SerilogWinEvtID.EventIdProvider())` ... also, since I'm developing an app vs a library; I'm not sure why the preference for MS?

Comment: I deleted my original comment as I was wrong about Serilog's `ForContext`. The MEL equivalent of `ForContext` is to just specify the `TContext` as a generic type arg for `ILogger<T>` in your constructor, as MEL's DI registration takes care of the rest.

Comment: Using Serilog directly doesn't really offer that many advantages over MEL (I use MEL as a frontend for Serilog myself), and if you use MEL then you make your life easier if you ever want to spin-off parts of your application as a reusable library. A huge reason to _not_ use Serilog's `static Log` property is because it makes it impossible (literally, yes) to factor-in your code's logging behaviour in your unit and integration tests.

Comment: @Dai can you provide the modified constructor in code as an answer pls?  I've attempted this as well, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: `services.AddLogging` will add MEL, so you're already using MEL _and_ Serilog together. I think those `ILogger<T>` errors are because you're inadvertently referencing `global::Serilog.ILogger` instead of MEL's `ILogger`. You should (for now) fully-qualify the `ILogger` type-names to avoid ambiguity (as both MEL and Serilog use the same type-names, which is unfortunate).

Comment: @Dai I may be using MEL & Serilog, but I still can't access `.ForContext` ... also, wrt MEL vs Serilog, this is why I thought it wouldn't matter (in my case) ... https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/104

Comment: Re: that Github link, that's me in there (same penguin avatar), so this amuses me

Comment: The `.ForContext` method is only available on `global::Serilog.ILogger`, _not_ MEL, so if you're getting errors then it means you're using MEL's `ILogger` instead of Serilog's `ILogger` - this is why I say you should fully-qualify your type-names (for now) to avoid this ambiguity and **don't** have `using:` statements for both namespaces in the same `.cs` file.

Comment: @Dai I thought the same, & I did try `public Worker(Serilog.ILogger<Worker> logger` but I get the following error:  CS0308 The non-generic type 'ILogger' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: That's because Serilog's `ILogger` isn't generic. (As far as I know) Serilog doesn't _automagically_ set `ForContext` when a `Serilog.ILogger` is a constructor param, you need to do it yourself, and that's only if your DI framework supports it (e.g. [SimpleInjector does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620823/serilogs-ilogger-injected-using-log-forcontextt-where-t-is-the-consumer), but MEDI does not) - that's why I recommend using MEL for ctor params instead, as MEL (with Serilog) _will_ call `ForContext` behind-the-scenes for you.

Comment: @Dai if I try to change it to non-generic, then I get multiple `CS0229 Ambiguity` errors for `'Worker._logger' and 'Worker._logger'`, etc, and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Remove the `using:` statements then and fully-qualify the type-names.

Comment: @Dai I don't know how to: use MEL for ctor params instead, so that MEL (with Serilog) will call ForContext behind-the-scenes for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242305/discussion-between-george-2-0-hope-and-dai).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Preface:

- This answer uses "MEL" as an abbreviation for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`.
- Because the type-name `ILogger` is used by both MEL *and* Serilog for completely different types, this answer *always* disambiguates occurrences of the name `ILogger` as either `MEL.ILogger` or `Serilog.ILogger`.

  - Though note that only MEL's `ILogger<T>` is generic. **There is no `Serilog.ILogger<T>`**, only `Serilog.ILogger`.

### TL;DR (for `.ForContext`):

- [`Serilog.ILogger.ForContext(String propertyName, Object? value, Boolean destructureObjects = false)` creates a "child" `Serilog.ILogger` instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637669/how-to-use-serilog-forcontext) with a single event-property added to all events logged by the child logger.

  - Whereas in MEL, you would typically use `ILogger<T>`'s `BeginScope` in a `using( log.BeginScope(...) )` block and passing `state: Dictionary<String,Object?>` parameter), which has different semantics to `ForContext`. This is why you should never mix Serilog idioms with MEL idioms.
- `Serilog.ILogger.ForContext(Type)` and `Serilog.ILogger.ForContext<TSource>` are both equivalent to calling `ForContext(String)`.

  - <sub>(`ForContext<TSource>()` passes `typeof(TSource)` into `ForContext(Type)`, and `ForContext(Type)` just passes `Type.FullName` into `ForContext(String)`)</sub>.
- The MEL equivalent of `ForContext<TSource>` is to either....

  - ...use constructor parameter dependency injection by injecting MEL's `ILogger<TSource>` as a `TSource` constructor parameter.
  - Inject (or otherwise obtain) a reference to MEL's `ILoggerFactory` and specify `TSource` as a generic type argument for the `.CreateLogger<T>` extension method.
  - Both of these approaches will make the MEL `ILoggerFactory` add a `"SourceContext"` (or "Category") event-property for `typeof(TSource).FullName` for you automatically during injection.
- So if you are injecting MEL's `ILogger<TService>` into your `class TService`'s constructor then...

  - ...**you don't need to call `ForContext` yourself** to set `"SourceContext"` (or "Category").
  - And you should be using MEL's `ILogger.BeginScope()` instead of `Serilog.ILogger.ForContext` for when you want to add more event-properties inside your service.
  - If you try to use `ForContext` with MEL's `ILogger` (both the generic and non-generic versions) you'll get a compiler error, ditto if you try to use `BeginScope` with `Serilog.ILogger` - simply because those are extension methods that are only defined for their intended types.

### Read on...

There are 2 different ways to use MEL and Serilog together in an application using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

1. Use Serilog only as a (host-specific) backend for MEL, while using MEL for the "frontend" `MEL.ILogger<T>` interfaces that are injected into your types' constructors.
2. Use Serilog directly in your own code (either with the `static` members of `global::Serilog.Log`, or by injecting `global::Serilog.ILogger`) while still wiring-up MEL for Serilog so that other components (that you didn't write) that use MEL will still appear in Serilog output.

[Option 2 is the preference of Serilog's author](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/104)...

> In application code, I use `Serilog.ILogger` and `static global::Serilog.Log.*` methods exclusively.
>
> I also dislike having to clutter every constructor with `MEL.ILogger<T>` parameters (constructor argument lists are highly-valuable real estate), and find there are usability issues once code steps out of DI and starts calling non-DI-instantiated classes that want to do some logging (more parameter passing).

...however I (respectfully) disagree with @nblumhardt's reasoning because:

- Using any [impure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268851/what-is-a-pure-function) (i.e. non-side-effect-free) `static` APIs in general (not just Serilog's `Serilog.Log`) is a bad idea because managing `static` state in unit and integration-tests is very difficult, if not impossible, depending on the API you're using and how your test-runner works.

  - For example, if you want your unit-test or integration-test to make assertions about what was logged by your SUT then you *cannot* use concurrent test execution: they must be strictly sequential so that your test-environment can reset or reconfigure the `Serilog.Log` for each test case, otherwise all of the test output will be munged together.
- The reasoning for avoiding "usability" and how "constructor argument lists are highly-valuable real-estate" are couched in ergonomics, or even mere *aesthetics*, however this is probably the *worst* reason for not doing something properly: "I'm going to cause engineering problems for myself because of aesthetics" is not a good case to present to your project's engineering manager.
- While I appreciate that having ctor params makes it harder to reuse a class in situations where DI is unavailable, using the `static Serilog.Log` methods is no-better: it means it's now harder to reuse your class in situations where the static Serilog types are unavailable.

  - My preferred solution to that situation is to either define a static factory method for that type which supplies stock or NOOP implementations of `MEL.ILogger<T>` (e.g. [`NullLogger<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions.nulllogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)) or define an alternative constructor that supplies its own defaults (and apply `[ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor]` to the DI constructor).
  - Also, `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` is now established as *the* baseline logging library which is present in every .NET environment now - given any random `.csproj` project created in the past 5 years, it's far more likely that `MEL.ILogger<T>` will be available instead of (if not in addition to) the `Serilog` NuGet package.

    - It's only bare-bones console projects and older codebases, that aren't using `IHost`, that won't have MEL available. Also, *every* ASP.NET Core project has MEL anyway.

Things are different if you're using a different DI system, such as Simple Injector, Autofac, Ninject, and others, so please *don't* follow this post's advice if you're *not* using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` directly.

---

For option 1, this is how I do it in my projects:

- If this is a multiple-project solution, with a single "entrypoint" `.exe` project that references your other projects...

  - Then the `.exe` project should reference the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`, `Serilog`, and `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` NuGet packages.
  - The other projects only need to reference [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/) (and *not* the main `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` package).
- If this is a single-project solution, then reference `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`, `Serilog`, and `Serilog.Extensions.Logging`.
- If you're using `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` or `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` then those methods already call `.AddLogging` for you already, you don't need to do it yourself, but you do need to call `UseSerilog` (`Serilog.SerilogHostBuilderExtensions.UseSerilog`) on the `IHostBuilder` before `.Build()` is called.

  - You also do not need to call `.AddSerilog` either.
- Inside your service-types (i.e. your types that have service interfaces in their constructor params) use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T>` where `T` is the same type as the constructor's declaring type (yes, I agree this is redundant).

  - So you should not have `using Serilog` in any other `.cs` files besides your `Program.cs` file (and/or the file where your `configureLogger` method is).
- Then, at runtime, when the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` container instantiates your types, it will call `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory.ILoggerFactory.CreateLogger(String categoryName)` for you automatically.

  - (Where the `categoryName` is the type-name of `T` in the injected `MEL.ILogger<T>` type)
  - ...which is passed-along to Serilog's `ForContext` logger factory, and the returned `Serilog.ILogger` is wrapped by MEL's `MEL.ILogger<T>`.

---

An actual example:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

// No `using Serilog` here.

static async Task<Int32> Main( String[] args )
{
    using( IHost host = CreateHost( args ) )
    {
        await host.RunAsync();

        return 0;
    }
}

static IHost CreateHost( String[] args )
{
    IHostBuilder b = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder( args );
    // CreateDefaultBuilder calls `MEL.AddLogging` for you already.
    b = b.UseStartup<YourStartupClass>(); // or `b.ConfigureServices()`;

    // Explicit extension method call because there's no `using Serilog` to avoid ambiguity issues:
    b = global::Serilog.SerilogHostBuilderExtensions.UseSerilog(
        builder             : b,
        configureLogger     : ConfigureSerilog,
        preserveStaticLogger: true
    );

    return b.Build();
}

static void ConfigureSerilog( HostBuilderContext ctx, Serilog.LoggerConfiguration logCfg )
{
     _ = logCfx
        .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .MinimumLevel.Is( /* etc */ )
        .WriteTo.File( /* etc */ );
}
```

**ExampleServiceType.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

// No `using Serilog` here either.

public MyService
{
    private readonly ILogger log;

    public MyService( ILogger<MyService> log )
    {
        this.log = log ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(log));
    }

    public void Foo( String name )
    {
        this.log.LogInformation( "hello {Name}", name );
    }
}
```

If you see yourself reusing `MyService` in places where DI is unavailable, then you can define an alternative constructor, like so:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

// No `using Serilog` here either.

public MyService
{
    private readonly ILogger log;

    [ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor]
    public MyService( ILogger<MyService> log )
    {
        this.log = log ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(log));
    }

    public MyService()
        : this( log: NullLogger<MyService>.Instance )
    {
    }

    public void Foo( String name )
    {
        this.log.LogInformation( "hello {Name}", name );
    }
}
```

So this will *just-work* (though when using `NullLogger<T>` specifically, *nothing will be logged*, so that may-or-may-not be desirable):

```
void Bar()
{
    MyService svc = new MyService();
    svc.Foo();
}
```

Comment: +1 good complete answer but have to take issue with a strawman:
_you then cannot unit-test or integration-test your class, nor can you feasibly mock/stub/fake the static dependency you're using._

The/Nick's point is if you are not explicitly testing the logging, do it statically. Nothing prevents you* from surfacing the dependency explicitly as needed (and fulfilling it with `Log.Logger` in a prod composition root) if you need to control it in the context of a test, *but that is a very rare thing*.

Comment: @RubenBartelink You are correct. I should rephrase that.

Comment: @RubenBartelink I've rewritten my bullet-point about testing with statics.

Comment: its better now but I would recommend that instead of talking about it as a disagreement that you just talk about where this does not make sense. For me its important though to acknowledge that people hardly ever a) test or b) (arguably) test logging in code. The point I, Nick and others are making is "for app code where you are not testing the logging, don't add all the noise that you would add for testing until you are actually doing that". Will delete all my comments later...

Comment: @RubenBartelink But I _do_ actually test my application-code, so I wouldn't say "where it doesn't make sense", because to me, it _always_ makes sense :)

Comment: Note your observations and reasoning about the general aesthetics and tradeoffs aside from this are fine (even if I don't happen to agree with them and would tend to default to using static Serilog for simplicitly -- to some degree this choice is for me also influenced by the fact I default to Pure DI without a container)

Comment: _But I do actually test my application-code,_ I am not saying you or others dont or shouldnt do that. I am saying that one is not typically mocking and verifying the logging aspect, so in a test context its perfectly fine for the code to write to an unitialized static logger in the context of a test.

Comment: For integration tests, I'll often wire a logger to the `ITestOutputHelper` etc and feed log output out from fixtures and/or app logic via something like https://github.com/jet/dotnet-templates/blob/4344ab0b6f9c3a07de1bde3e8a9ec0efa20ccf38/equinox-shipping/Watchdog.Integration/SerilogLogFixture.fs#L3. However that should not be confused with this being a generally good pattern - Tests in general, but more importantly, Apps should not dump out mounds of junk and require a dev to come interpret it.

Comment: Good logging is succinct, and orthogonal to a good app. As such, arguably the logging tests should not be intermingled with the application logic even if you do test it. On the other hand, for libraries that are intended to produce specific logging, you sometimes want to know that they work and log correctly in failure paths and hence absolutely will test that aspect. Even then though, you want to do validation of log messages on a semantic basis as much as possible, rather than pinning specific messages based on regexes or string compares, which is a recipe for messy application monitoring.

Comment: @RubenBartelink Of course, that's just being sensible: when my tests do assert expected log output they look at the structured log entry, not flat/rendered strings.

Comment: Yes, but that subtlety is often lost on people that are starting to use Serilog etc and/or doing testing, so is worth calling out. I am not suggesting you don't understand any of the above and/or that your tests would not consider that factor.

Comment: @RubenBartelink I don't agree that using static `Serilog.Log` is "cleaner" though - let's just agree to disagree.

Comment: I'm not seeking to drain your or my day through an argument, and I accept that the 'cleaner' judgement is subjective. I think your post makes the case well, and I can see that viewpoint as being valid (and very useful for others that take the view that MEL and DI are ubiquitous and something to hence lean on).

Comment: My only quibble is that: _is a bad idea because managing static state in unit and integration-tests is very difficult, if not impossible, depending on the API you're using and how your test-runner works._ is still a strawman argument as written. *If* you need to test logging, it obv makes no sense to leave it static. *But* the argument is that the noise reduction by using `static Log` is a win _until you *need*_ to do that, _and you can then change it just in time in the cases where you are doing it_ - that even makes that case stand out better.

Comment: I removed my original comment and reposted ^. When you remove your last "agree to disagree" comment and either a) repost it now or b) do an edit that removes my argument, I'll remove this and/or the comment too.

Comment: @RubenBartelink You're taking StackOverflow far too seriously. If you really care that much then just edit my post.

Comment: You may be very right indeed ;) but for me editing someone's post is crossing a line. I'm making the argument here as I believe you've taken the time to argue an important case well. As I say, my quibble is with you diluting the central counterpoint: nobody tests logging so that's a bad reason to follow the pattern/dogma. Happy to leave the thread as is, but even happier if we can follow through to make it a canonical post putting the argument for having logging follow [referential transparency rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) without a strawman testing argument.

Comment: @RubenBartelink C#/.NET does not support referential-transparency, that's kinda moot.

Comment: I appreciate that; neither does F# or .NET in general ;) My point is that part of the case for using statics is just that: passing loggers around even when you could pass them out of band via them being `static` is not really part of the C# idiom, especially when you consider the fact that logging is orthogonal to working code, conceptually does not have side effects, and is guaranteed not to throw. Are we giving up on the agreeing to disagree ;P

Comment: @RubenBartelink I'm going to bed